# Express static file only working in one route

Tags: node.js, express

The problem is static files(css,js)  only working on one route but not others.For template I am using handlebar, here is my code snippets :

```
var express = require('express'),
    ........
    exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

auth = require('./routes/auth')(Account);
.........
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use('/auth', auth); //static files not working

app.get('/', function(req, res) {   // static files working
    res.render('index');
});
```

for `/auth` route, I am getting 404 status

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path for auth?

auth = require('/installdir/abc/routes/auth')(Account);

Comment: You should show the template you're using for the page(s) served under both `/` and `/auth` so we can see how you're referencing your static assets.

Comment: are the url for your static assets in your template absolute or relative? They should be absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem using absolute url in templates